# Collapse Bootstrap height 100%

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, twitter-bootstrap

Quando clica no nome de cada produto o `collapse` aparece com o efeito padrão.
O problema é que o `collapse` não ocupa 100% da `div`.

Segue exemplo do problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(".collapse.show").collapse('hide');
});
$('.item-produto').on('click', function () { 
    $('.bloco-lista').css('display','none');
});
```

```css
#produtos .bloco-produto {background-color:  #000;color: #fff;padding: 68px 0; }
#produtos h2 {font-size: 58px;font-size: 3.625rem;font-weight: 600;margin-bottom: 80px;}
#produtos p {font-size: 30px;font-size: 1.875rem;font-weight: 200;text-align: justify;}
#produtos .logo-divider {position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50% , -50%);}
#produtos .bloco-lista {background-color: #77a074;color: #000;padding: 68px 0;}
#produtos .bloco-lista .clear-flex {padding-left: 90px;}
#produtos .bloco-lista .clear-flex h3 {font-size: 30px;font-size: 1.875rem;font-weight: 200;display: inline-block;width: 49%;margin:  30px 0;cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="produtos">
    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="d-none d-md-block col-md-1 bloco-produto"></div>
         <div class="col-12 col-md-2 bloco-produto">
                <h2>Produtos</h2>
                <p>Lorem iAsum dolor sit amet,  ovq consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy sedjooa nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore manga aliquam erat volutpat. nonummy sedjooa nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore manga aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="d-none d-md-block col-md-2 bloco-produto"></div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="container-produtos vertical-center bloco-lista" id="list-produtos">
                    <div class="clear-flex">
                        <h3 class="item-produto" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cursos" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="cursos" id="cursos_head">Cursos</h3>
                        <h3 class="item-produto" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tributaria" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="tributaria" id="tributaria_head">Consultoria tributária</h3>
                        <h3 class="item-produto">Consultoria societária</h3>
                        <h3 class="item-produto">Captação de recursos</h3>
                        <h3 class="item-produto">Estruturação de negócios</h3>
                        <h3 class="item-produto">Fusões e aquisições</h3>
                        <h3 class="item-produto">Gestão de projetos</h3>
                        <h3 class="item-produto">Incorporação de imóveis</h3>
                        <h3 class="item-produto">Planejamento estratégico</h3>
                    </div> 
                </div> 

                <!-- descrição dos produtos -->
                <div class="collapse" id="cursos" aria-labelledby="cursos_head" data-parent="#list-produtos">
                    <div class="container-mostra-produto bloco-produto h-100">
                        <div class="clear-flex">
                            <h2>Cursos</h2>
                            <p>Lorem iAsum dolor sit amet,  ovq consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy sedjooa nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore manga aliquam erat volutpat. nonummy sedjooa nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore manga aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="collapse" id="tributaria" aria-labelledby="tributaria_head" data-parent="#list-produtos">
                    <div class="container-mostra-produto bloco-produto h-100">
                        <div class="clear-flex">
                            <h2>Consultoria</h2>
                            <p>Lorem iAsum dolor sit amet,  ovq consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy sedjooa nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore manga aliquam erat volutpat. nonummy sedjooa nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore manga aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>

            <!-- ALTERNAR CLASS "BLOCO LISTA E BLOCO PRODUTO" QUANDO CLICAR NO PRODUTO -->
            <div class="d-none d-md-block col-md-1 bloco-produto"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Adicione `.collapse{ height: 100% }` no CSS e veja se resolve.

Comment: Coloca height: 100% aqui também `#produtos .bloco-lista {height: 100%}`

Comment: Sim isto resolve, foi o que eu tinha feito antes mesmo de postar a pergunta, o problema é que o efeito simplesmente some.

Comment: O efeito acontece até certo ponto. Depois vai direto pro height.
https://i.imgur.com/2wWwW4M.gif